# How to start Y Axis Line at 0 from right for negative values in chart js 2?

Tags: charts, chart.js, yaxis

I wanted to know if there are any options to set in chart js 2.6 so that the Y Axis line start from right to left for negative values, in bar chart.

Currently, this is how it shows up for negative values (#2 chart in fiddle):
https://jsfiddle.net/j6nqt4oo/1/

Code for reference:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart2").getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'horizontalBar',
    data: {
        labels: ['A', 'B'],
            datasets: [{
                data: [-10, -20]
            }]
    },
    options: {
    responsive: false,
        showDatapoints: true,
            scales: {

                maintainAspectRatio: true,
                responsive: false,
                xAxes: [{

                    ticks: {
                       beginAtZero: true

                    },
                    gridLines: {
                        display: false
                    }
                }],
                yAxes: [{

                    gridLines: {
                        display: false
                    }
                }]
            },

            legend: {
                display: false
            }
    }
```

But this is how I want: (Y axis grid line at 0 and A and B are on the right)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set **`position`** property to **`right`** for y-axis ticks, in your second chart ...

```
...
yAxes: [{
   position: 'right',
   gridLines: {
      display: false
   }
}]
...
```

Here is the [**working demo on JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/qLgv4peh/)